# Serving .APK file from IIS 8

Tags: iis, permissions

I have created an .APK mime type and put up a test APK on the default IIS site.  Everything downloads fine on an Android handset.

Mime-type : **application/vnd.android.package-archive**

I've then created a NEW site to host this file and added the same mime-type etc.  When I download the file on an Andoird handset it sees the site, link and file, and when selected it begins a download but immediately fails.

The filename is  and the error message is "Download Unsuccessful".

Even changing to a default mime-type - **application/octet-Stream** same problem occurs.

I'm sure its a configuration or permissions issue for IIS but I cant figure out what.  I've replicated the NTFS permissions from the default wwwroot folder to this new site.

The only difference is the new site is HTTPS while the default site is HTTP.  If I allow HTTP on the new site it works fine.

EDIT:  Forgot to add that a desktop browser (Chrome and IE) both download the file fine from the default and new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a certificate error.  In the test environment the root CA was not trusted.  Once this was trusted it worked fine.